# Can't Boot Into Windows XP

Tags: 14.04

I set up Ubuntu 14.04LTS on an old Dell Laptop as a dual booting system.  I have attempted to boot into WindowsXP on startup just to see if it would work and it gives me a blue screen saying that "windows has been shut down to protect..."

I don't really need to boot into Windows, I just know that you are supposed to be able to, it boots into Ubuntu without an issue.  Is there something I could do to get past the error?  I am not an expert but I could successfully follow any instructions that this community is willing to give me, thank you.

Comment: Did you resize your XP partition using tools from the linux side?  I did, and it broke my XP installation.  If that's the case, you will need to run windows repair tools to fix it.  To set this up successfully, you need to resize the Windows partition using Windows tools.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try to update grub (command `update-grub`).

If this didn't work, you can try to boot from a windows cd and do a [repair install](http://www.michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm#RI). Afterwards (as windows will have destroyed your grub boot loader), you need to [reinstall grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) from a linux live cd.

If you don't want to risk your data, create an image first. You may also want to mount that image inside [a virtualbox container](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox) - if you don't really need to boot into windows anyway, this may be a more useful option.